# What is the default interface on a fresh Kubuntu installation

Tags: kubuntu

I'm going to install kubuntu, what is the default interface when installing KUBUNTU ?  Does plasma installed by default ?

Sorry for the rookie question. Is there a point where i'm asked which interface i want to use ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will install plasma by default without asking you, but then you can change.  If you want to choose during the installation Debian does it.